# python subprocess(or related) - load psql dump, got error - '<' ignored

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using call method to load sql dump:

```
 call(["psql", "-U", "user", "name", "<", "pathtofile"])
```

This is directly logging into postgres and ignoring "<" and pathtofile.

```
 psql: warning: extra command-line argument "<" ignored
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `stdin` keyword argument if you want redirection:

```
with open("pathtofile", "rb") as f:
    call(["psql", "-U", "user", "name"], stdin=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to this:

```
 call(["psql", "-U", "user", "name", "<", "pathtofile"], shell=True)
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

"<" is an input redirection operator, and must be interpreted by a shell.  If you don't say `shell=True`, it's passed to `psql` as an argument, and `psql` has no idea what to do with it.

Edit:  in general, what @falsetru suggested is a better approach, because passing arbitrary strings to shells can be dangerous.  But if you *need* to use shell operations, `shell=True` is the way to do it.